# Open Sharepoint https URL in windows file explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-explorer

I am trying to open my sharepoint folder structure in windows explorer as it want to access sharepoint folder from office desktop (using office addin).

Some thing like

```
window.open('file:///https://servername.sharepoint.com/teams/')
```

but this doesnot work. It gives Access is denied error.

I tried with below things. 
First I tried

```
window.open('file://servername.sharepoint.com/teams/')-
```

It opened link in file explorer but as http request. which is causing authentication issue after getting file.
Then I tried:

```
window.open('file:///https%3A%2F%servername.sharepoint.com/)-
```

I tried using escape sequence and many more combinations, bt nothing seems to be working

I want to open sharepoint folder structure in windows explorer, but for that document to open without error the link in windows explorer should be https

[windows explorer with sharepoint URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySzBo.png)

why windows explorer - to give office add-in integrated look, i do not want to open sharepoint link in browser. so i tried open dialog box, but in open dialog box we cannot set location path. 
So at last we decided to go with windows explorer

Comment: Windows File Explorer is not a browser.

Comment: Can you tell us what the actual goal is? Why would you want to open a web page in Windows's Explorer?

Comment: From my Office add in task pane, i want user to have option to open file from sharepoint project without going to browser,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open SharePoint folder URL path in file explorer as follows

for http url (http://my-domain.sharepoint.com/teams/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/)

```
 window.open('file://my-domain.sharepoint.com/teams/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/', '_blank');
```

for https url(https://my-domain.sharepoint.com/teams/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/)

```
window.open('file://my-domain.sharepoint.com@SSL/teams/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/', '_blank');
```

Comment: yes it works!!!

Comment: Where do you type these commands?